# Which Nenya ring is correct?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, galadriel

Which Nenya, ring of Galadriel is the "correct" one?
I want to buy one to my girlfriend as an engagement ring.
I mostly find this design:

[image: Nenya in silver without a diamond]

However, I found it only made of silver - not suitable for an engagement ring.
Then, I found this one [here](http://badalijewelry.com/Nenya-The-Ring-of-Galadriel.html):

[image: Nenya in white gold with a diamond]

which is also offered in a white gold version and also looks more like an engagement ring. However, it looks completely differently than the other Nenya I found.

How is it possible that there are two different "original" designs of Galadriel's ring over the internet? Should the other ring be also considered as Galadriel's ring? Any advice/information appreciated.

Comment: the ring doesn't have a description other being silver/white gold and containing a gem presumably a diamond. It honestly would probably be of a simpler design as the elves seem to find beauty in simplicity. i think, haha. however the first ring is what they designed for the movies and it looks much cooler.

Comment: This actually comes down to more the taste of your girlfriend. If it would mean more to have the ring from the movie, option A. If it would mean more to her to have a Diamond option B.

Comment: Based on the movies, the upper ring is the "correct" one. If the other one is marketed as Galadriel's ring, it may be based on the brief description in the book.

Comment: Unless Tolkien drew a design himself, it's all ultimately fan fiction. That said, (1) I'm pretty sure her ring is described in the books as having a stone, and (2) just use the interpretation you like best.

Comment: And do drop by and tell us how it goes.

Comment: Well, thanks for advices :) I'll probably take the second one, as 1) it has a stone (which is correct in respect of book's description as you wrote here) 2) it is made of materials worthy of engagement ring :)

Comment: And why is silver not considered suitable for an engagement ring? It is a precious metal, just like gold, and these days, the conventional ideas of what is considered acceptable or appropriate for engagement rings are, thankfully and at long last, being cast aside. What is suitable is that which carries the most meaning between the giver and the recipient, and that can be forged of any metal or design, plain or adorned with stones. If sterling silver seems a bit too common, why not look into fine silver (.999 pure) or Argentium silver, which is mixed with germanium and slightly purer than ...

Comment: ... sterling at .935, hypoallergenic, naturally tarnish resistant and made from reclaimed silver, so it's also earth-friendly?

Answer (score 22):

There is no "correct" depiction.

The descriptions of the Rings in the books lacks this level of detail; first of all we have words of Saruman:

> "The Nine, the Seven, and the Three," he said, "had each their proper gem. Not so the One. It was round and unadorned, as it were one of the lesser rings; but its maker set marks upon it that the skilled, maybe, could still see and read."

And then the description of Nenya itself:

> ...a ring about her finger; it glittered like polished gold overlaid with silver light, and a white stone in it twinkled as if the Even-star had come down to rest upon her hand.

So there's just not enough information there, although I'd say that the lower image is closer to the book's description.

Answer (score 3):

According to the books neither of the designs is "incorrect" because there is no description in the book so specific and detailed that it will be possible to determine which of these rings is more accurate.
One description of Nenya can be found in *The Fellowship of the Ring*,  Book Two, Chapter VII-The Mirror of Galadriel, which describes it thus:

> Eärendil, the Evening Star, most beloved of the Elves, shone clear above. So bright was it that the figure of the Elven-lady cast a dim shadow on the ground. Its rays glanced upon a ring about her finger; it glittered like polished gold overlaid with silver light, and a white stone in it twinkled as if the Even-star had come down to rest upon her hand.

It is also said by Galadriel herself in the same chapter that:

> This is Nenya, the Ring of Adamant, and I am its keeper.

These words from Galadriel could indicate that maybe the white stone in Nenya is indeed the mythical stone Adamant but since it's not written anywhere and Tolkien have scarcely written anything about Adamant or referring to it in his books we can't know if it's true or not.

Another description of Nenya is give in *The Return of the King*, Book Six, Chapter IX-The Grey Havens, in which it is described as follows:

> ...Nenya, the ring wrought of *mithril*, that bore a single white stone flickering like a frosty star.

Here we learn that Nenya is made of the precious mythical metal *mithril* which for obvious reasons there are no rings in our world that are wrought of it but the closest metal to *mithril* besides titanium in our wold according to its descriptions is probably silver with *mithril* being called also "silver-steel" and "Moria-silver" and even "true-silver" by men although it may not be appropriate for an engagement ring. And again there is a description of a white flickering stone which is likely (although not surely) a diamond or the mythical stone Adamant.

The conclusion is that there is no "correct" design of Nenya according to the books (although there are "incorrect ones" but neither of the depictions that you have presented here falls into this category). However the first design with the flower-like pattern is identical or almost identical to the depiction of Nenya in the movies.

Answer (score 1):

As user 8719 and Ofek Aman already said, there is no detailed description of the Nenya in the books.

But if you are thinking about the movies, the first one does look a bit like the one Cate Blanchett wore (bottom right one in the screenshot below).

[image: The three elven rings as seen in the movies]

Why do you think silver is innapropriate? [According to Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engagement_ring#Styles)

> Gold (Available in Yellow Gold, White Gold and Rose Gold) and platinum are preferred for engagement rings, but common metal types such as titanium, **silver**, and stainless steel are **also used for engagement rings**.

You give her the Nenya now, and then you can give her The One for the wedding (just kidding). Or you can coat it in gold before proposing. IMO giving her the Nenya makes it much more valuable than if it was a plain golden ring. I might become bi if a geek I admired proposed to me like that.

Comment: Well thanks for answer, but the question is 5 years old and we are already divorced by now (not because of the ring, I took the one from bad ali and it was successful actually)